# SVG circle stroke have a weird ending? How to spread the stroke dashes equally?

Tags: html, css, svg

I was looking at this

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/stroke-dasharray/

and then I was looking at this

https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/LGLzWq

I'm especially looking at the `stroke-dasharray` in this case in that code, not sure what is going on but, I think it is the ending of the stroke not sure how you can get it properly.

But basically this
[image with circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmcSt.png)

why is it happening and how to prevent it or choose one so that it fits with the lines and gaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `stroke-dasharray: 5;` you can use `stroke-dasharray: 5.227;` and the problem is solved. Why?

First: the total length of the path is 313.6517333984375. You can calculate it by using the `getTotalLength()` method.

You next divide the length in equal parts for example dividing the total length by 60: 313.6517333984375 / 60 = 5.227528889973958

Please note that the divider has to be an even number. 61 won't do since you'll have a stroke at the beginning and another one at the end. You need a stroke at the beginning and a gap at the end.

```css
.stroke {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-dasharray: 5.227;
}

/* DEMO STYLES */
body {
  background: #333;
}

.module {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

svg {
  fill: #333;
  stroke-width: 5%;
}
```

```html
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle class="stroke" cx="60" cy="60" r="50"/>
  </svg>
```

Comment: on codepen you can even tweek it live to find an acceptable value https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gOOwxpN from @revar linked pen

Comment: Oh and then you can use ``calc(313.6517333984375 / (10 * 2)`` if you want to focus on how many strokes you want or ``calc(313.6517333984375 / 20`` to focus only on how many strokes and gaps you want as in how to get the result or something. The thing is if not using id you have to add one manually and then use the function. Not sure if there is a way to get the entire path length with CSS but with JS it's fine too. Or a way to calculate it?

Comment: I don't think you can get the path length with CSS. Another way of getting the path length would be `2*Math.PI*r`   where r="50" (the formula for the circle's circumference) The result would be a little different but I don't think it matters.

Comment: If you look at the result more closely (e. g. when using a finer division) you will find that the mathematically motivated arc length calculation as mentioned by @enxaneta leads to better results than the `.getTotalLength()` approach. For some reason the latter returns a slightly too small number.